# Anypoint Studio forward payload to HTTP service

Tags: anypoint-studio, apikit

I am using APIkit that forwards a Json message to my backend java REST service.  I am passing the following body from the APIKit console:

```
{"firstname": "sonam", "lastname": "jango" }
```

Before calling the HTTP service, I have a Set Payload component  that is supposed to extract the message with the following:

```
#[{'firstname': message.payload.firstname, 'lastname': 'kong'}]
```

but it does not work.

How do I forward the payload that came in from APIkit Console to my backend service?

thanks
-Sonam

Comment: what is the error you get?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the MEL expression `#[messge.inboundProperties.firstname]` you can find more info on this link [enter link description here](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/mule-expression-language-mel)